# Null pointer exception in REST service while return bean class as json

Tags: java, rest

I am using a REST service in my project.

When I convert a bean class into json string (return type is String) using

```
return new Gson().toJson(myoutput);
```

It will accept and work properly. 
If I return my bean class directly without convert into String (my return type is my bean class name), it will produce null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ObjectGraphImpl.getFields(ObjectGraphImpl.java:94)
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:105)
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createObjectGraph(MoxyObjectProvider.java:91)
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.transform(MoxyObjectProvider.java:78)
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.transform(MoxyObjectProvider.java:63)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.AbstractObjectProvider.createFilteringObject(AbstractObjectProvider.java:135)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.AbstractObjectProvider.getFilteringObject(AbstractObjectProvider.java:97)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.AbstractObjectProvider.getFilteringObject(AbstractObjectProvider.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.internal.FilteringMoxyJsonProvider.preWriteTo(FilteringMoxyJsonProvider.java:80)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:807)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:263)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:89)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:621)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:377)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:367)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:711)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My method:

```
public class FilterService {
    public FilterService() { }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getFilterById() throws BaseException {
        Filter filter = this.filterProcessor.getById();     
        return new Gson().toJson(filter);
    }
}
```

My method, I try to return as bean

```
public class FilterService {
    public FilterService() { }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Filter getFilterById() throws BaseException {
        Filter filter = this.filterProcessor.getById();     
        return Filter;
    }
}
```

It will show error.

My bean class:

```
public class Filter  {
    private List<Fields> and;

    public List<Fields> getAnd() {
        return this.and;
    }

    public void setAnd(List<Fields> and) {
        this.and = and;
    }   
}
```

Comment: DTO means? Not understood

Comment: Can you post your method & bean here?

Comment: I guess its some thing version problem.

Comment: What is `this.filterProcessor` ? Is that `null`?

Comment: No. I will create object for that processor it will not null.